# Why is caret train taking up so much memory?

Tags: r, memory, glm, r-caret

When I train just using `glm`, everything works, and I don't even come close to exhausting memory. But when I run `train(..., method='glm')`, I run out of memory.

Is this because `train` is storing a lot of data for each iteration of the cross-validation (or whatever the trControl procedure is)? I'm looking at `trainControl` and I can't find how to prevent this...any hints? I only care about the performance summary and maybe the predicted responses.

(I know it's not related to storing data from each iteration of the parameter-tuning grid search because there's no grid for glm's, I believe.)

Comment: Care to make a small reproducible example for others to try?

Comment: This is 7 years old and presumably the issue was fixed versions ago. What version did this happen in and can you confirm what version solves it?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The problem is two fold. **i)** `train` doesn't just *fit* a model via `glm()`, it will bootstrap that model, so even with the defaults, `train()` will do 25 bootstrap samples, which, coupled with problem ii) is *the* (or *a*) source of your problem, and **ii)** `train()` simply calls the `glm()` function with *its* defaults. And those defaults are to store the model frame (argument `model = TRUE` of `?glm`), which includes a copy of the data in model frame style. The object returned by `train()` already stores a copy of the data in `$trainingData`, and the `"glm"` object in `$finalModel` also has a copy of the actual data.

At this point, simply running `glm()` using `train()` will be producing 25 copies of the fully expanded `model.frame` *and* the original data, which will all need to be held in memory during the resampling process - whether these are held concurrently or consecutively is not immediately clear from a quick look at the code as the resampling happens in an `lapply()` call. There will also be 25 copies of the raw data.

Once the resampling is finished, the returned object will contain 2 copies of the raw data and a full copy of the `model.frame`. If your training data is large relative to available RAM or contains many factors to be expanded in the `model.frame`, then you could easily be using huge amounts of memory just carrying copies of the data around.

If you add `model = FALSE` to your train call, that might make a difference. Here is a small example using the `clotting` data in `?glm`:

```
clotting <- data.frame(u = c(5,10,15,20,30,40,60,80,100),
                       lot1 = c(118,58,42,35,27,25,21,19,18),
                       lot2 = c(69,35,26,21,18,16,13,12,12))
require(caret)
```

then

```
> m1 <- train(lot1 ~ log(u), data=clotting, family = Gamma, method = "glm", 
+             model = TRUE)
Fitting: parameter=none 
Aggregating results
Fitting model on full training set
> m2 <- train(lot1 ~ log(u), data=clotting, family = Gamma, method = "glm",
+             model = FALSE)
Fitting: parameter=none 
Aggregating results
Fitting model on full training set
> object.size(m1)
121832 bytes
> object.size(m2)
116456 bytes
> ## ordinary glm() call:
> m3 <- glm(lot1 ~ log(u), data=clotting, family = Gamma)
> object.size(m3)
47272 bytes
> m4 <- glm(lot1 ~ log(u), data=clotting, family = Gamma, model = FALSE)
> object.size(m4)
42152 bytes
```

So there is a size difference in the returned object and memory use during training will be lower. How much lower will depend on whether the internals of `train()` keep all copies of the `model.frame` in memory during the resampling process.

The object returned by `train()` is also significantly larger than that returned by `glm()` - as mentioned by @DWin in the comments, below.

To take this further, either study the code more closely, or email Max Kuhn, the maintainer of **caret**, to enquire about options to reduce the memory footprint.

Comment: Good answer (as typical for you, Gavin). Would only add the size of the glm object: `> m3= glm(lot1 ~ log(u), data=clotting, family = Gamma)
> object.size(m3)
47272 bytes`

Comment: @Dwin Thanks, and good point. I will add that output to the Answer, with attribution of course.

Comment: Thanks, I asked Max to add an answer here.

Answer (score 32):

Gavin's answer is spot on. I built the function for ease of use rather than for speed or efficiency [1]

First, using the formula interface can be an issue when you have a lot of predictors. This is something that R Core could fix; the formula approach requires a very large but sparse `terms()` matrix to be retained and R has packages to effectively deal with that issue. For example, with n = 3, 000 and p = 2, 000, a 3–tree random forest model object was 1.5 times larger in size and took 23 times longer to execute when using the formula interface (282s vs 12s).

Second, you don't have to keep the training data (see the `returnData` argument in `trainControl()`).

Also, since R doesn't have any real shared memory infrastructure, Gavin is correct about the number of copies of the data that are retained in memory. Basically, a list is created for every resample and `lapply()` is used to process the list, then return only the resampled estimates. An alternative would be to sequentially make one copy of the data (for the current resample), do the required operations, then repeat for the remaining iterations. The issue there is I/O and the inability to do any parallel processing. [2]

If you have a large data set, I suggest using the non-formula interface (even though the actual model, like glm, eventually uses a formula). Also, for large data sets, `train()` saves the resampling indices for use by `resamples()` and other functions. You could probably remove those too.

Yang - it would be good to know more about the data via `str(data)` so we can understand the dimensions and other aspects (eg. factors with many levels etc).

I hope that helps,

Max

[1] I should not that we go to great lengths to fit as few models as possible when we can. The "sub-model" trick is used for many models, such as pls, gbm, rpart, earth and many others. Also, when a model has formula and non-formula interfaces (eg. `lda()` or `earth()`, we default to the non-formula interface.

[2] Every once in a while I get the insane urge to reboot the `train()` function. Using `foreach` might get around some of these issues.

Comment: Welcome to SO @Max, and thanks for the informative Answer. I'm glad you wrote `train()` for ease of use; I've been using it recently for some stochastic gradient boosting and having written some tuning code myself it was a revelation to switch to **caret** and `train()`!

Comment: I'm supplying my own model matrix and response vector (necessarily so that I can use `findCorrelation`), so I don't use any model's formula interface. What's the sub-model trick?

Comment: What packages are those you have mentioned to deal with formula's memory usage issue? "and R has packages to effectively deal with that issue"

Comment: Correct. Especially the part regarding formula interface may cause also memory issues

Answer (score 7):

I think the above answers are a bit outdated. The caret and caretEnsemble packages now include an additional parameter in trainControl 'trim.' Trim is initially set to FALSE but changing it to TRUE will significantly decrease model size. You should use this in combination with returnData=FALSE for the smallest model sizes possible. If you're using a model ensemble, you should also specify these two parameters in the greedy/stack ensemble trainControl.

For my case, a 1.6gb model shrunk to ~500mb with both parameters in the ensemble control and further shrunk to ~300mb also using the parameters in the greedy ensemble control.

```
Ensemble_control_A9 <- trainControl(trim=TRUE, method = "repeatedcv", number = 3, repeats = 2, verboseIter = TRUE, returnData = FALSE, returnResamp = "all", classProbs = TRUE, summaryFunction = twoClassSummary, savePredictions = TRUE, allowParallel = TRUE, sampling = "up")


Ensemble_greedy_A5 <- caretEnsemble(Ensemble_list_A5, metric="ROC",  trControl=trainControl(number=2, trim=TRUE, returnData = FALSE, summaryFunction=twoClassSummary, classProbs=TRUE))
```