# huge size in model output from train function in r caret package

Tags: r, r-caret, training-data

I am training a bagFDA model using `train()` function in r caret package, and save the model output as a .Rdata file. the input file is about 300k records with 26 variables, but the output .Rdata has a size of 3G. I simply run the following:

```
modelout <- train(x,y,method="bagFDA")
save(file= "myout.Rdata", modelout)
```

under a window system.
question: (1) why `myout.Rdata` is so big? (2) how can I reduce the size of the file?

Thanks in advance!

JT

Answer (score 4):

In the `trainControl` set `returnData = FALSE` for starters, so your not creating an extra copy of the data in the model.  My understanding is the with bagFDA you are creating a number of bootstraps, which essentially create the same number of copies of your data. lowering the B parameter, defaulted to 50, should shrink it as well
Also, check out this post:

[Why is caret train taking up so much memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543999/why-is-caret-train-taking-up-so-much-memory)